# Oracle pl/sql map with value is array

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

I need create associative array where key is VARCHAR(20) and value is array of varchars.
For example:

```
customer_by_locations: {
   "London": {
               "John Doe", "Samantha Simpson", "Nicolas Darcula"
             },
   "Stambul": {
               "Abdula Ibn Rahim", "Another Abdula"
             }
}
```

I have created query:

```
declare 
  type customers is varray(10) of varchar2(20);
  type locations is table of customers index by varchar2(20);

  list_locations locations;
  list_customers varchar(20);
begin
  list_locations('London') := ("John Doe", "Samantha Simpson", "Nicolas Darcula");
  list_locations('Stambul') := ("Abdula Ibn Rahim", "Another Abdula");

  for i in 1 .. list_locations loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total ' || list_locations(i));   
    //Something do 
  end loop;  
end;
```

But I have error

> PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Please, tell me, how i will declare array as value and assign values in it in oracle pl/sql.

Comment: Have you tried this: `list_locations('London') := '"John Doe", "Samantha Simpson", "Nicolas Darcula"';`?

Comment: Yeah, i have tried this. The same error.

Comment: Oh well I think your loop is wrong ... you can't go from 1 to London. You want this: `for i in 1 .. list_locations.count loop` See e.g. here: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/coll/iterate.html

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I really forgot about array count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare 
  type customers is varray(10) of varchar2(20);
  type locations is table of customers index by varchar2(20);

  list_locations locations;
  list_customers varchar(20);
  v_location varchar2(20);
begin
  list_locations('London') := customers('John Doe', 'Samantha Simpson', 'Nicolas Darcula');
  list_locations('Stambul') := customers('Abdula Ibn Rahim', 'Another Abdula');

  v_location := list_locations.first;
  loop
    exit when v_location is null;

    for i in 1 .. list_locations(v_location).count loop
      dbms_output.put_line(v_location||': '||list_locations(v_location)(i));
    end loop;

    v_location := list_locations.next(v_location);
  end loop;
end; 
/
```